# Converting String to datetime with a specific initial format

Tags: python

I scraped some dates with this format:

```
review_date = ['9 August 2018 ', '7 August 2018 ']
```

and I wanted to convert each string to a datetime format like this '%d-%m-%Y'

```
for d in review_date:
     d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

but the following error is appearing because it isn't in the inicial format datetime wants

> ValueError: time data '9 August 2018 ' does not match format
>   '%d-%m-%Y'

Is there an easy way to convert this or do I need to replace my string?

Comment: your format needs to match the string you are trying to convert, not the format that you want it in - that's implicit in using strptime. Hint: %B is for month names.

Answer (score 2):

`strptime` converts the string to a `datetime()` object. The format string you pass to it is to specify the format the string is already in:

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y') # %B is the full month name
```

You can generate any string you want from that object later with `strftime()` - then you can pass the format you want:

```
s = d.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

You can chain the calls in a single line:

```
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%d %B %Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```